# TypeScript converts boolean to string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following problem: within the following code, I'm trying to check, if the variable result is true or false:

```
    const result: boolean = await this.sqlConnector.validatePassword
        (this.userData.getUserId(), validatorContext.recognized.value);
    // Returns string
    console.log(typeof(result));
```

The function `sqlconnector.validatePassword` is also returning a boolean. The header of the function looks like that:

```
public validatePassword (userId: string, userInput: string): Promise <boolean>
```

However, the `typeof(result)` function is saying, that the variable is from type string.
This finally leads to the fact that the following if statement always fails.

```
    // always false because no boolean
    if (result === true) {
        return true;
    } else {
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: well why does sqlConnector.validatePassword return a string?

Comment: I dont know :D. I have set the return value to boolean. It looks like that: 

        return new Promise ((res, rej) => {
            this.con.query(getResult, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    rej (false)
                } else {
                    res (result[0].isSecretCorrect);
                }
            });
        })

In both cases, im receiving an string.

Comment: what does `result[0].isSecretCorrect` return?

Comment: TypeScript types are compile-time, not run-time. So it doesn't matter that you've declared `result` as a `boolean`.

Comment: It returns true. The sql statement looks like that: SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT secretPassword FROM person WHERE personID = '' AND secretPassword = '') THEN true ELSE false END AS isSecretCorrect;

Comment: TypeScript doesn't convert your values, since it is just JavaScript superset. And your app actually runs JS. So, if some function returns `string`, you'll get a string, despite `boolean` annotation in TS code.

Comment: you will have to look to see what `sqlConnector` is doing.

Comment: Can you, please. try `this.con.query(getResult, (err, result) => { if (err) ... }` refactor to `this.con.query(getResult, (err, result) => res(true))` and tell us, if the return value is still a string. If yes, then whether you use native promises or some library for them?

Comment: It returns a value from type boolean. Im using native promises.

Comment: Then the only answer I can come up with, that `result[0].isSecretCorrect` is actually a `string` at the moment, when it passes to the `res` function.

Comment: Ok, thank for your help guys! I will try to find the error. Otherwise i will use the answer from dince12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are being passed back a string value. This should be fixed within the code that is returning the response. As a temporary measure you could check the string for what it is and use it in a similar way. Should hold while response if fixed.

```
if (typeof result === "string" && result === "true") {
    return true;
}
```

you could also check the response and change it accordingly.

```
let result: any = await this.sqlConnector.validatePassword
(this.userData.getUserId(), validatorContext.recognized.value);


if (typeof result === 'string'){
  result = result === "true";
}
```

Most of all though I would recommend getting the response to be returned as type Boolean if that is what is intended allowing for simple checks like.

```
if (result) // as long as result is true
{
  //you will end up here
}
```